# In group theory how to calculate negative powers of multiplication modulo

Tags: group-theory

In $\mathbb{Z}_n=(na; n\in z)$,
we can list elements by taking n both positive and negative.

$Ex- In(\mathbb{Z}_8,+)={0,1,2,....7}$ to check if $1$ is a generator
$<1>={n(1);n\in \mathbb{Z}}$, if I choose $n=-2$ as ${6 \equiv -2 \pmod 8}$.

Similarly in

$U(8)={1,3,5,7}{a^n ;n\in \mathbb{Z}}$

To check if $3$ is a generator:

$<3> = {3^nmod8 ; n\in \mathbb{Z}}$

How can I calculate $3^{-2}\pmod8$ if I take $n=-2$?

Comment: This is very hard to read. Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3^2\equiv1\bmod8$ hence for any $n\in\Bbb Z,$ $3^n\equiv1\bmod8$ if $n$ is even and $3^n\equiv3\bmod8$ if $n$ is odd.

In your group "$U(8)$", the subgroup $\langle 3\rangle$ is simply $\{1,3\}$. Similarly, $\langle 5\rangle=\{1,5\}$ and
$\langle 7\rangle=\{1,7\}.$

Other example: in "$U(7)$", $2^3\equiv1$ hence $2^{-1}\equiv2^2,$ $2^{-n}\equiv2^{2n},$ and
$\langle 2\rangle=\{1,2,4\}.$

Answer (score 0):

There is a well-known algorithm that, given two integers, $x$ and $y$, yields integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ax+by=\gcd(x,y)$. Since 3 and 8 are relatively prime,we can find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $3a+8b=1.$ Then $a$ is the reciprocal of 3 in the ring $\mathbb {Z/8Z}.$ Your answer is the remainder after $a^2$ is divided by 8.